# Library on simplifying a tetrahedral mesh

Tags: c++, graphics, mesh

I am wondering whether there is any existing library or software which is on tetrahedral mesh simplification and written in C/C++. You may know that there is a famous algorithm on triangular mesh based on Quadric Error Metrics, called [Surface Simpliﬁcation Using Quadric Error Metrics](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4162/html05s/garland97.pdf). I reckon there should be something similar but applied to tetrahedral mesh. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably search in CGAL library [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). Its the best for computational geometry algorithms. I am sure that someone should have already implemented mesh simplification in CGAL.

Comment: Hi, I have checked but found no issue about tetrahedral mesh simplification. If you ever found any, please indicate it for me. Thanks!

Comment: check this [link](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.5/doc_html/cgal_manual/Surface_mesh_simplification/Chapter_main.html)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find anything about TETRAHEDRAL MESH. I am not talking about triangular surface mesh.

Comment: Why don't you convert it to triangular?

Comment: Tetrahedral mesh is used to descretize a volume space, while triangular mesh can only represent surface, no volume. Once converted into triangular, information about volume will lost, which means some space is not covered by geometrical objects. So I cannot do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can find to what you are looking for exists [here](http://mattgong.yolasite.com/mesher.php)  it allows tetrahedral volumetric rendering.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, as the original question and the comments seem to differ slightly in the end aim.

Let me know if you need any further info:)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yet what I am looking for is a simplification algorithm for tetrahedral mesh, i.e. given a mesh which consists of millions of tetrahedrons then we simplify it to thousands of ones. The link you showed me should be on mesh generation.